# emcee performing poorly for simple minimization

Tags: python, python-2.7, minimization, mcmc, emcee

I'm trying to set up a Benchmark for several optimizing algorithms. One I'm currently failing with is the "MCMC Hammer" emcee.
I don't know if I did not set it up correctly or if my plot is not working as it should.
The goal is to minimize a test function, e.g. rosenbrock, and plot the accepted function values against the function calls. I'm uncertain because the performance and final result is poorly and the plot does not have the "hairy caterpillar" look. Maybe somebody has some experience with emcee and can give me a hint. Thanks in advance!

Here is some code, the first half is the setup and plot routine, the second half is the actual emcee:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
n_dim = 5
NoR = 1 #number of runs
problem = 3 #choose test function

if( problem==1 ) :
    functionname = "norm(r)"
    def testfunction(x) :
        return (np.sum(np.power(x, 2.0)) + 1.0e-99)
    solutionX = np.zeros(n_dim)
    solutionY = 1.0e-99

elif( problem==2 ) :
    functionname = "Rosenbrock"
    def testfunction(x) :
        return np.sum(100.0*np.power( x[1:]-np.power(x[:-1],2),2 ) + np.power(1.0-np.array(x[:-1]),2)) + 1.0e-99
    solutionX = np.ones(n_dim)
    #np.concatenate(( [-1.0], np.ones(n_dim-1) )) 
    solutionY = 0.0 

elif( problem==3 ) :
    functionname = "Schaffer"
    def testfunction(x) :
        return sum((x**2+x1**2)**0.25 * ((np.sin(50*(x**2+x1**2)**0.1))**2+1.0) for x, x1 in zip(x[:-1], x[1:]))
    solutionX = np.zeros(n_dim)
    solutionY = 0.0 


calls = {} # dictionary; missing entries will be automatically created
y_hist = {};
y_best = {};

def testfunctionCount(x, solver) : # now general
    global calls
    #global trace
    calls[solver] += 1

    return testfunction(x)

# one plotting routine for all solvers:
def plot_solver( solver, log=False, y_hist_bins=20 ) :
    # General statistics:
    y_hist[solver] = np.array( y_hist[solver] ) # allow for transposing etc
    hist_len = len( y_hist[solver] )
    print "Number of valid hops:", hist_len
    print "Function calls:", calls[solver]
    print "best value", np.amin(y_hist[solver])
    # Plots:
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(12,6))
    # y(function calls) :
    if( log ) :
        ax[0].semilogy( y_hist[solver][:,0], y_hist[solver][:,1], "x-" )
        if( solutionY > 0.01 ) : ax[0].axhline(y=solutionY, color="k") # y=0 does not look good
    else :
        ax[0].plot( y_hist[solver][:,0], y_hist[solver][:,1], "x-" )
        ax[0].axhline(y=solutionY, color="k")
    ax[0].set_xlabel("function calls")
    ax[0].set_ylabel("y")
    # y-histogram:
    ax[1].hist( y_hist[solver][:,1], bins=y_hist_bins, log=log )
    ax[1].axvline(x=solutionY, color="k")
    ax[1].set_xlabel("y")
    ax[1].set_ylabel("occurrences")
    plt.show()

    return

# State what is being used:
print "function:       ", functionname
print "dimensionality: ", n_dim


import emcee

solver = "emcee"


nwalkers = 10000

def hbprior(x):
    if -10.0 < x.all() < 10.0:
        return 0.0
    return -np.inf

def hbprob(x):
    hbp = hbprior(x) 
    if not np.isfinite(hbp) :
        return -np.inf
    return hbp + testfunctionCount(x, solver) # "+" only because hbp==0 

x0 = np.random.rand(nwalkers, n_dim) #starting point

y_best[solver] = []
for x in range(0, NoR): #number of runs
    calls[solver] = 0
    #y_hist[solver] = []

    sampler = emcee.EnsembleSampler(nwalkers, n_dim, hbprob, a=2.0)
    n_burnin = 1
    x_pos, prob, state = sampler.run_mcmc(x0, n_burnin) # burn in
    sampler.reset()
    #calls[solver] = 0; # possible, but the burn-in also costs
    n_walk = 100
    sampler.run_mcmc(x0, n_walk)

    print "Mean acceptance fraction: " + "{0:.3f}".format(np.mean(sampler.acceptance_fraction))

    y_hist[solver] = np.transpose( np.array( [ np.arange( nwalkers*(1+n_burnin+1)+1, calls[solver]+1, 1 ), \
        np.array( [ testfunction(np.array(x)) for x in sampler.flatchain ] ) ] ) )
    # this is not very elegant, maybe there is a better way?
    y_best[solver].append(np.amin(y_hist[solver]))
    plot_solver( solver, y_hist_bins=np.linspace(0.0,1.0e3,50) )



y_best[solver] = np.array( y_best[solver] )
y_best_mean = np.sum(y_best[solver]) / NoR
y_best_best = np.amin(y_best[solver])
print "best", y_best_best
print "mean", y_best_mean
```